# Extracting Data from HTML Span using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract"1.02 Crores" and "7864" from html code and save them in different column in csv file.

Code:

```
<div class="featuresvap _graybox clearfix"><h3><span><i class="icon-inr"></i>1.02 Crores</span><small> @ <i class="icon-inr"></i><b>7864/sq.ft</b> as per carpet area</small></h3>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the actual data but this is just something that I threw together really quick. If you need it to navigate to a website then use `import requests`. you'' need to add `url = 'yourwebpagehere' page = requests.get(url)` and change `soup` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')` then remove the `html` variable since it would be unneeded.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

html = '<div class="featuresvap _graybox clearfix"><h3><span><i class="icon-inr"></i>1.02 Crores</span><small> @ <i class="icon-inr"></i><b>7864/sq.ft</b> as per carpet area</small></h3>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
findSpan = soup.find('span')
findB = soup.find('b')
print([findSpan.text, findB.text.replace('/sq.ft', '')])

with open('NAMEYOURFILE.csv', 'w+') as writer:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(writer)
    csv_writer.writerow(["First Column Name", "Second Column Name"])
    csv_writer.writerow([findSpan, findB])
```

Answer (score 0):

self explained in code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# data for first column
firstCol = []
# data for second column
secondCol = []

for url in listURL:
    html = '.....' # downloaded html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # 'select_one' select using CSS selectors, return only first element
    fCol = soup.select_one('.featuresvap h3 span')
    # remove: <i class="icon-inr"></i>
    span.find("i").extract()
    sCol = soup.select_one('.featuresvap h3 b')
    firstCol.append(fCol.text)
    secondCol.append(sCol.text.replace('/sq.ft', ''))

with open('results.csv', 'w') as fl:
    csvContent = ','.join(firstCol) + '\n' + ','.join(secondCol)
    fl.write(csvContent)

''' sample results
1.02 Crores | 2.34 Crores
7864        | 2475

'''
print('finish')
```